# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function with toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I tried to use jquery with toggle function I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

When I click the div first time it will show left to right then throws this error and it will stop there. It wont hide when I click again. This is the code I am using.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#slideMenuHeader").click(function () {
        //$("#cbp-spmenu-s1").slideToggle("slow");
        var anim = "slide";
        var duration = 500;
        var options = { direction: 'left' };
        $("#cbp-spmenu-s1").toggle(anim, options, duration);
    });
});
```

If I use toggle without options object and duration it is working fine. But I want left to right toggle. Why I am getting this error?

I am using JQuery 1.10.2

Comment: I think you need to review the docs for [jQuery `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
1> You will have to include `jQuery UI` also.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/)

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: $('.mySelect').val() };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;

    $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

2> You can do it wihtout `jQuery UI` as well:

**Working Example**
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o97rzj6v/)

Comment: I am also doing the same thing but not working for me. See the code I provided.

Comment: @sree you can add jquery ui as well along with jquery.

Comment: @Sree You will have to include `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js` this js as well. After main JS

Comment: After adding JQuery Ui the animation is working but the animation not starting at the correct position as it do with default toggle function. Why is that behaviour?

Comment: Is it not possible without adding jquery UI because in my entire application I am not using any jquery UI. Only for this fix I have to add.

Comment: Since when does [jQuery `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) depend upon jQuery UI?

Comment: @Sparky Read the question and answer **carefully**. Or read the code ***carefully*** or specifically this line `$('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);`.

Comment: Read ***carefully*** [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484055/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-with-toggle-function/27484132?noredirect=1#comment43400975_27484132).  The OP never mentions jQuery **UI**, which means that `(effect, options, duration)` is the root of his mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), toggle() takes up to three optional arguments in the following formats

```
.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )
.toggle( options )
.toggle( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

In your code, you are passing three arguments, so jquery thinks you are passing a duration, an easing function, and a callback to be triggered on completion.

But you are passing an options object, not an easing function. That's why I would guess it is erroring. What you need to do is use the second format, and pass a single options object, with properties for duration and direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but there is no direction property in options. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Looks like you need to use 'step' value to determine the direction. Where did you get the idea of 'direction' from?

Comment: In that case, I would guess you are using a different version of Jquery or Jquery UI than that fiddle is using. If you change the version in the jsfiddle, and run, then you get the 'not a function' error. Did you try doing it as I suggested yet?

Answer (score -2):

To use all animation you will need to include `jQuery UI` with `effects`

If you dont want to use jQuery UI you can use below code for simple `toggle`

```
$("#cbp-spmenu-s1").toggle(200); //use anim, options, duration to pass arguments
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: I am passing the arguments as you can see the code I provided. The default animation is not left to right.

Comment: This answer does not make sense at all.

Comment: sorry guys, fixed my answer.